# Detect text source from accessibility service

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I'm using an accessibility service to receive text from a view of a specific app. The text can be inserted manually or via voice. Is there any way to check the source? I'd like to change my behavior if the text is inserted manually or not.

Comment: "The text can be inserted manually or via voice" -- what does this mean? "Is there any way to check the source?" -- what does this mean?

Comment: Quite a good question. You can definitely check if an accessibility service is enabled or not (some banking apps do that in fact, and might not work if any accessibility service is enabled). But whether it was used for inserting text in your text view, or if the text was inserted by touch events. I guess the accessibility service is not your own, right?

Comment: @CommonsWare I receive feedback (via accessbility service) about the events on a third-party app. In this app the user can write text in a view OR insert text with the voice. I'd like to know if the text come from voice or not.

Comment: @Trinimon The accessibility service is implemented in my app to monitor the events in a third-party app. The user can insert text in this third-party app using the keyboard or using the voice. I'd like to know if the text I read via accessibility service comes from user voice or not.

Comment: I'm not aware that the accessibility APIs make a distinction between sources of text, and outside of that, there should be no reliable way for you to determine it by other means.